# Cartesian product from hash values in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, key-value, cartesian-product

Given that we have a hash structure like this one {:s=>[1, 2, 3], :c=>["r", "g", "b"]}, how can we compute the cartesian product of the key values in this scenario. The number of key-value pairs in the hash are dynamic in nature and could vary. Any Help would be much appreciated.....

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. We'd like to see evidence of your effort. Did you research this? If not, why? If so, why didn't it help? Did you write code? If not, again, why? If so, what is the smallest piece of code the demonstrates the problem you encountered, along with the required input data and expected output? Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   h = { a: [1, 2, 3], b: [:d, :e, :f], c: ["g", "h", "i"] }

   first, *rest = h.values
   first.product(*rest)
     #=> [[1, :d, "g"], [1, :d, "h"], [1, :d, "i"], [1, :e, "g"],
     #    [1, :e, "h"], [1, :e, "i"], [1, :f, "g"], [1, :f, "h"],
     #    [1, :f, "i"], [2, :d, "g"], [2, :d, "h"], [2, :d, "i"],
     #    [2, :e, "g"], [2, :e, "h"], [2, :e, "i"], [2, :f, "g"],
     #    [2, :f, "h"], [2, :f, "i"], [3, :d, "g"], [3, :d, "h"],
     #    [3, :d, "i"], [3, :e, "g"], [3, :e, "h"], [3, :e, "i"],
     #    [3, :f, "g"], [3, :f, "h"], [3, :f, "i"]]
```

See [Array#product](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-product).

Alternatively, one could write:

```
values = h.values
values.shift.product(*values)
```